# Many2many domain doesn't work in form view shown by adding a line in an One2many field

Tags: odoo

I have 3 model A, B and C as described below

[image]

When I create a new B in A.b_ids I use a separated form view for B that hides a_id. Although after creating that new B, its a_id will be automatically filled with the id of A in the current context, its a_id is null before creating. And because of that, the domain of c_ids is broken - it's supposed to work with the id of A in the context.

Is there a way to make the domain work as supposed?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand it fully, but have you tried to make `c_ids` on `B` just a related field to `A.c_ids`? I mean following field definition for `B.c_ids`: `c_ids = fields.Many2many(related="a_id.c_ids")`.

Comment: No. `B.c_ids` can be changed and is a subset of `A.c_ids`.

Comment: Okay, so related is no option.

Comment: Perhaps you can make `c_ids` a computed field based on `a_id` ? Since `a.c_ids` is the subset of `b.c_ids`, you may consider filtering out `a.c_ids` by `a_id`. Like
`rec.c_ids = rec.a_id.c_ids.filtered([(rec.a_id.id, 'in', 'a_ids')]) for rec in self`